# Force grunt-typescript to use node_modules/.bin/tsc

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, typescript

How do I force *grunt-typescript* to use the local typescript instance in my *node_modules/.bin* folder? My global instance of typescript is 1.4 and I want to try out 1.5Beta without affecting any other project I have.

Comment: A package that supports it https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code of grunt-typescript, I think, the typescript compiler is loaded from `node_modules` and then if it is not found in the `node_modules` folder is loaded from the global environment.

Relevant points in the source code :

- [Import statement](https://github.com/k-maru/grunt-typescript/blob/master/src/modules/compiler.ts#L9)
- [CreateProgram](https://github.com/k-maru/grunt-typescript/blob/master/src/modules/compiler.ts#L139)

Node require documentation loading priority:

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders